# How to communicate from Child Component to Parent Component with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I have a main component `App` containing some children according to the routes (I use `react-router`) etc :

```js
class App extends Component {

    otherClick = () => { /* run every children's `handleButton2` function */ }
    <div className="App">
         <Button handleMenuClick={this.toggleSideBar}>Button 1</Button>
         <Button handleOtherClick={this.otherClick}>Button 2</Button>
         <SideBar ref="sideBar" title="Toto"/>
          {this.props.children}
    </div>
    }
```

So, according to the route, `App` will contain some other containers such as:

```js
class ContainerABC extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    handleButton2 = () => {
        let sc = this.refs.subCont;
        sc.setState({visible : !sc.visible});
        // Change the color of Button 2 ???
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <SubContainer ref="subCont"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

The role of Button 2 depends on the current Container. In the example above, when I have a `ContainerABC` as child, I want that `Button 2` toggles the `SubContainer` of `ContainerABC`.

How can I tell to Button 2 to do the appropriate action according to the child of the component ?
And/or how can I modify `Button 2` (or any trigger) from `SubCont` when `Button 2` triggers an action on `SubCont` ?

Maybe using Redux ? I don't see how it could be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redux *might* help only because it can trigger an action that, in return, modifies the global state tree (e.g. redux store through a reducer). If that's the only purpose you need fulfilling, then I'd recommend against adding complexity (as much as I fancy Redux).

I assume you want a random child from `{this.props.children}` fire a random action once Button 2 is clicked?

Let's observe this commonly enforced React pattern:
*Properties flow downwards. Actions (read: callbacks) go upwards.*

That said, you may want to iterate through your `{this.props.children}` and check for the existence of a special callback prop that adheres to your API requirements.

```js
React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
    if (typeof child.props.toggleButton2State !== "function")   {
        throw('Woah, cowboy, you need that toggleButton2State function);
    }
}
```

Then your button could cycle through children in the same manner and execute that function, if exists.

```js
handleButton2Click() {
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, (child) => {
        if (typeof child.props.toggleButton2State === "function")   {
            child.props.toggleButton2State.call(child, !oldState, this);
        }
    }
}
```

So you just called child's callback function in scope of the child with boolean state being toggled and you also passed the reference to the parent component (this).

I would strongly suggest you never manipulate the parent container from a child. You never know how your hierarchy may change.

Obviously, this is a very rough example but it should get you going. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: How can I expose `toggleButton2State` from the child to the parent ? Because the parent doesn't have access to child method and it is not actually a `prop`

Comment: You don't. Properties go downwards (parent to child) and actions flow upwards (in form of callbacks supplied through props).

Comment: So your solution doesn't work. I will use redux it will be easier. Because, I don't know the children contained in the parent. So parent cannot pass a prop. The function is a part of the child component

Comment: Now the children can fire an action modifying the state of Button2

Comment: I gave you the bounty because your answer is interesting anyway

Answer (score 0):

If the behavior of the button depends on what container is being rendered, then it sounds to me like the container should render the buttons. You could wire up some props (could even use [cloneElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to put them on the children) so you can pass callbacks down that would change the behavior of the button, but that sounds like a nightmare to maintain.

You could put those buttons in a separate component (with a prop to determine what they do) and render it in the containers. That sounds much simpler to me.